# Disable Autoplay in haml

Tags: html, iframe, video, haml, autoplay

I'm embedding a video into a page via the iframe tag but am looking for a way to turn off the autoplay feature. Here's what I've tried so far:

**Mark-Up**

```
%iframe{:controller => "0", :height => 390, :width => 480, :frameborder => "0", :src => "//cassininazir.com/embed/he-man.mp4", :autoplay => "false"}
```

**I also tried adding a param:**

```
%param{:autoplay => "false"}
```

Since I've used the iframe tag instead of the embed tag, I'm thinking maybe this is why the `autoplay="false"` argument won't work. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source video that the `iframe` references uses a `video` tag.

The cause is that pesky `"autoplay"` attribute in the source `video` tag.

It would be easiest to copy the video html from the source and add it to your Haml like this (without the `autoplay` attribute):

```
%video{ controls: "", name: "media"}
  %source{src: "http://cassininazir.com/embed/he-man.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
```

Although you may be able to remove the "autoplay" attribute with jquery after the element is loaded, I think the above approach is easiest.

**Here's a link to a [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EAGKk).**